# How to update/delete sqlite table row knowing its index

Tags: java, sqlite

So I want to be able to update only one row knowing the index of it for example the second row or third row but all tutorials I find use conditions that use set values from the columns, is there no way to use the Index?
One answer I found was to add an ID column that just holds the number of the row starting from 1 and updates with each new row, but that quickly went downhill when I started deleting rows because the IDs stay the same for example if I had IDs like {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and 3 is deleted the column would remain as {1, 2, 4, 5} which would ruin other operations. Any tips?

Comment: Using the "index" doesn't make sense, becaues there is no such thing as an index as you're describing. Rows and results are returned in the order you specify (or the table's specified ordering). To this end, entries in a relational db often have some form of an `id` field for quick reference

Comment: @Rogue The reason I need to use an index is because I am making a GUI application using JavaFX and displaying the contents of the table inside a TableView, from this TableView the user can select any row and be able to edit or delete it. This is why I need to be able to access rows via an index just so that the user can select it on the front end, and for the table I am using it doesn't really make much sense to make a sorted unique id for each row,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this:

```
CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS table(
    custom_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Now insert some values into it and run `SELECT rowid,* FROM table;`

```
rowid  custom_id     name
1      1              a
2      2              b
3      3              c
4      4              d
5      5              e
```

Delete some rows:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE rowid = 3;
DELETE FROM table WHERE rowid = 4;
SELECT rowid,* FROM table;
rowid  custom_id     name
1      1              a
2      2              b
5      5              e
```

Run special command `VACUUM;`

```
SELECT rowid, * FROM table;
rowid  custom_id     name
1      1              a
2      2              b
3      5              e
```

Now your **rowid**, which could act as an **index** for you, has been updated.

Let me know if that helped :)